# How can one measure gravity with thermodynamic means following Verlinde?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity

Verlinde's description of gravity implies that it has to do with entropy and temperature of the vacuum. Curved vacuum has a temperature.

But temperature is a scalar, and curvature is not. How does one measure gravity with temperature and other thermodynamic quantities in Verlinde's appraoch?

For example, how can one measure the direction of gravity with vacuum thermodynamics?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Verlinde, but skimming through the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0785.pdf) it looks like the "vanilla" version is derived assuming there is one holographic direction, so acceleration is not really a vector in that version. To generalize the argument to higher dimensions, Verlinde acknowledges "In fact, it may appear somewhat counter-intuitive that the temperature $T$ is related to the vector quantity $a$" Then after some argumentation, "we conclude that acceleration is related to an entropy gradient."

Comment: @Andrew If acceleration is related to an entropy gradient, can the magnitude of acceleration be related to temperature? Are the pedagogical articles about this somewhere?

Comment: I am not aware of a pedagogical reference, and like I said I'm not an expert in this field. My understanding skimming the paper is that there's some kind of map from the "fundamental" degrees of freedom and "spacetime". That mapping defines level sets of the Newtonian potential. The entropy gradient sets the direction in which the potential is decreasing/increasing most rapidly, and the temperature sets the magnitude of the increase/decrease. I'm not going to lie, I have personally always found these ideas difficult to grasp (and somewhat vague).